# Is it possible to apply DDD with generic classes and dynamic queries retrieval?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I´m wondering if it´s possible to use DDD without using EF's stuff, cause in my project the classes are generic complex types with generic inheritance that may vary from time to time, also the DB tables and fields may vary from one client DB version to another, also the queries to the database that are dynamically constructed depending of the generic object that it's produced.

I'm currently taking into consideration this design pattern:
[DDD N-Layered .NET 4.0 Architecture Guide](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysoftwarebrasil.googlecode.com%2Fsvn%2Ftrunk%2FApostilas%2FN-Layered_Domain_Oriented_Architecture_Gu.pdf&ei=ag41VfDnNMfaaPemgUA&usg=AFQjCNHx-myttEEeUuE9bGuKZzqvdXS5yA&sig2=pO-t4JxMN35HYoJKUIg0AA&bvm=bv.91071109,d.d2s)  by Cesar de la Torre among others.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: sure, DDD is a general approach and not linked to a specific technology

Answer (score 3):

DDD isn't related to persistence technology (a.k.a EF, NHibernate). DDD is more related to your domain concepts. When you work with DDD is useful to implement Repository Pattern to handle persistence scenarios. Your repository receive your complex business object and transform it to a more persistence-friendly version.

Example:

```
interface IMyRepository {

   void Save(MyComplexBussinessAgg aggregate);

}

class MyRepository: IMyRepository {

   public void Save(MyComplexBussinessAgg aggregate) {

      //Pseudo Code
      //1.- Check valid state of MyComplexBusinessAgg
      //2.- Transform to a persistence-friendly DTO
      //3.- Persist

   }

}
```

When you need to work with dynamically behavior, you should consider use a better approach like EventSourcing, or change your persistence technology to NoSql database provider to avoid future issues and boost your project. Embrace the changes of your model in the project architecture and the project will be success.

Comment: Validation doesn't belong in the repository and I'm not sure why you would need an extra DTO layer for persistence. Most ORM's can map the objects directly.

Comment: The experience shows if you work with ORMs you should need to populate your domain classes with virtual properties, collections hacks and something else. The question here is about DDD, if you want to be a good DDD practitioner, you need to think in terms of your domain classes, if you modeling your domain to be persistence friendly, then you limit your domain classes. Repository only needs to known if the aggregate is in valid state.